# Name the process using the most CPU without leading or trailing spaces

Tags: conky

I use the variable `${top name 1}` in Conky to display the name of the process utilizing the most CPU. The default size of `top_name_width=15`. I've tried the following Conky settings with no success

```
    top_name_width = 0,
    use_spacer = 'none'
```

Using `top_name_width=0` displays single character process name. Any suggestions to make it dynamic so that shorter process names do not cause leading/trailing spaces and longer process names do not get truncated?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to throw in a bit of Lua.

First, make a Lua function to call `top` and snip the whitespace off the end of its response, and save it in a file named, e.g., `snipws.lua`...

```
function conky_snipws()
    local s = conky_parse("${top name 1}")
    return string.gsub(s, "%s+$", "")
end
```

Then, at the top of the `conky.config` section of your `.conkyrc` file, put the following (adjusting the path as needed)...

```
lua_load = '~/bin/lua_scripts/snipws.lua',
```

...and in the `conky.text` section, put the following...

```
${lua conky_snipws}
```

You can also include a `top_name_width` assignment in the `conky.config` section to specify the maximum width of the name, up to 512 characters according to `man top`.